# How do I change the format of the axis label in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, axis-labels

If I plot a log scale graph, matplotlib gives me the nice looking entries 10<sup>5</sup>, 10<sup>6</sup>, ...

For readability I would however prefer the form 1e5, 1e6, ...

Can I directly set the axis properties to behave that way?

I rather ugly hack would be:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(1, 40, 100);
y = np.linspace(1, 5, 100);

# Actually plot the exponential values
plt.plot(x, 10**y)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_yscale('log')

# Rewrite the y labels
y_labels = ax.get_yticks()
ax.set_yticklabels(['1e%i' % np.round(np.log(y)/np.log(10)) for y in y_labels])

plt.show()
```

[image]

But surely there must be a better way.

Comment: There's probably some way with [`ticker`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html) and `FormatStrFormatter`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You use [`ticker.FormatStrFormatter('%0.0e')`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FormatStrFormatter). This formats each number with the string format `%0.0e` which represents floats using exponential notation:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

x = np.linspace(1, 40, 100)
y = np.linspace(1, 5, 100)

# Actually plot the exponential values
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, 10**y)
ax.set_yscale('log')

# Rewrite the y labels
y_labels = ax.get_yticks()
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FormatStrFormatter('%0.0e'))

plt.show()
```

yields

[image]

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. You didn't happen to know a way to  format `1e+04` to `1e4`?

Comment: Unfortunately, to control that [you would need to write a custom function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9910972/190597). If you do want to go down this path, note that you could use a `ticker.FuncFormatter`.

Comment: Well yeah, that's what I thought. But thanks anyway for your the help.