# Pad the exponential index with zeros

Tags: python

Let's say I have a double precision value

```
a = 1.5838619160273860E-021
```

Is there a way to create a string `b`

```
b = '1.5838619160273860E-021'
```

Note the index has three digits here `E-021` instead of `E-21`. I know `format(int, '0.16f')` can control the decimal place, but no idea how to manipulate the index.

Any input will be appreciated

Comment: they look the same?

Comment: @KyleFalconer that's the point, if you try to convert `a` back into a string `b` it drops the leading zero.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - number of digits in exponent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910972/python-number-of-digits-in-exponent)

Answer (score 0):

You need another case for when its +21 instead of -21

```
>>> x = '1.5838619160273860E-21'
>>> a,b = x.split('E-')
>>> 'E-'.join((a,b.zfill(3)))
'1.5838619160273860E-021'
```