# exponent digits in scientific notation in Python

Tags: python, scientific-notation, exponent

In Python, scientific notation always gives me 2 digits in exponent:

```
print('%17.8E\n' % 0.0665745511651039)
6.65745512E-02
```

However, I badly want to have 3 digits like:

```
6.65745512E-002
```

Can we do this with a built-in configuration/function in Python?

I know my question is basically the same question as: [Python - number of digits in exponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910972/python-number-of-digits-in-exponent), but this question was asked 4 years ago and I don't want to call such a function thousand times. I hope there should be a better solution now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - number of digits in exponent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910972/python-number-of-digits-in-exponent)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can not change this default behavior since you can not override the `str` methods.

However, you can wrap the float, and use the `__format__` method:

```
class MyNumber:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __format__(self,format_spec):
        ss = ('{0:'+format_spec+'}').format(self.val)
        if ( 'E' in ss):
            mantissa, exp = ss.split('E')            
            return mantissa + 'E'+ exp[0] + '0' + exp[1:]
        return ss


     print( '{0:17.8E}'.format( MyNumber(0.0665745511651039)))
```

Comment: Yes, the wrapping-the-float method perfectly works for print(). Thank you. However, I would also like to write the output to a file and it works only half way: 'ValueError: invalid literal for float(): -4.10522747+00' I need your help. Let me edit my original question to explain this error.

Comment: When the number is between 1 <= n < 10, the format doesn't work and simply shows 2 digits. `  -6.08474553E-001
  -4.10522747+00
  -4.75716448+00
  -1.58045329E-002
   4.72555542+00`
(It didn't work for print(), too.) Could you please fix this?

Comment: Updated for positive exponent

Comment: It works like a charm. Now it shows all in 3 digits. `  -6.08474553E-001
  -4.10522747E+000
  -4.75716448E+000
  -1.58045329E-002
   4.72555542E+000` Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own formatter and override `format_field`:

```
import string
class MyFormatter(string.Formatter): 
    def format_field(self, value, format_spec):
        ss = string.Formatter.format_field(self,value,format_spec)
        if format_spec.endswith('E'):
            if ( 'E' in ss):
                mantissa, exp = ss.split('E')
                return mantissa + 'E'+ exp[0] + '0' + exp[1:]                  
        return ss

print( MyFormatter().format('{0:17.8E}',0.00665745511651039) )
```