# Display a number in scientific notation with specific digits

Tags: python

i want to display numbers in scientific notation:

```
-407.45833
```

So far i used this:

```
        i = '%E' % Decimal(i)
```

result:

```
-4.074583E+02
```

now my question: how can i add one more digit so it looks like this:?

```
-4.074583E+002
```

I know i should find my answer in the tables from [Python string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to select the proper format layout, but i cant find it. Can someone tell me the result and where to find it please?

Comment: I don't believe there's a function for that...but you can do it manually:(

Comment: @abccd if i change this "%.2E" i get "4.07E+02". i did hope there is something similar for the digits at the end

Comment: No, unfortunately not, but why did you need to do that? What happens if it's E+0123? Now there's four digits....

Comment: i have to fill a text document with numbers like that and they have to have this specific format

Comment: have you looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9911741/1635109) ?

Comment: @Vipr0 you can use the function in my post to do the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's unfortunately not any direct way using string formatting to have three digits following the `+`. A easy method to replace it is to use this since what we know is that is exponential forms are all stored as strings, so all the string methods will work on it.

I wrote a little function that takes a regular scientific notation and returns a formatted notation with three digits after the `+`:

```
from decimal import Decimal
def pretty(notation, n):
    if '+' in notation:
        return "+".join([notation.split('+')[0],notation.split('+')[1].zfill(n)])
    return "-".join([notation.split('-')[0],notation.split('-')[1].zfill(n)])

i = '%E' % Decimal(-407.45833)
print(pretty(i,3)) # leave three digits
```

Comment: That's great, if it actually helped you, you can mark my answer as accepted by checking the ✅. And have a great day:)