# Round scientific value of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, rounding

I would like to gain space while saving my datas, I don't mind the loss of information. The data have many different of order of magnitude, So I cannot round using the normal rounding function.
I can't seem to find a post that help me to round my dataset using scientific numbers

12345678 => round with 3 decimals => 1.234E7

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137150/format-suppress-scientific-notation-from-python-pandas-aggregation-results

Comment: how are you saving the dataframe?

Comment: @Anwarvic I would like to "save" the dataframe with this setup, not only display it, so it doesn't really answer my question

Comment: @hpaulj I save it in csv files for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) with a `float_format='%.3E'` to ouput your (floating point) data rounded to 3 places in scientific notation to a csv file. See [the format specification](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) for other formatting options.

Minimal example:

```
pd.DataFrame([12345678]).astype(float).to_csv(float_format='%.3E')
#',0\r\n0,1.235E+07\r\n'
```

There's no easy way to have `E7` instead of `E+07`, see also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910972/number-of-digits-in-exponent).

Comment: It's perfect! Thank you!